# How can I connect Storm and D3.js using Redis and Flask?

Tags: java, d3.js, flask, redis, apache-storm

I have my Storm testing topology done, and before I created a d3 script on an Html code, that readed the data from a text file. I want it now to read the data directly from a Storm topology (a bolt maybe?) But I have no clue of how to do it. I'm using Horton Works Sandbox for the testing, Any help would be apprecieated.

Thanks in advance!

I've found a storm package for redis that I'm trying to use now. It allows you to set a bolt for writting on redis, and I've set the node already. My problem now is that eclipse can't find the imports of the java code and the ones on the pom.xml.I've downloaded the package. My current java bolt and imports are:

```
package Storm.practice.Storm.Prova;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.testing.TestWordSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;
import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import storm.external.*;// error from here
import storm.external.storm-redis.org.apache.storm.redis.common.config.JedisClusterConfig;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.config.JedisPoolConfig;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.mapper.RedisDataTypeDescription;
import org.apache.storm.redis.common.mapper.RedisStoreMapper;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCommands;//to here


..........
 class MortsStoreMapper implements RedisStoreMapper {
        private RedisDataTypeDescription description;
        private final String hashKey = "wordCount";

        public WordCountStoreMapper() {
            description = new RedisDataTypeDescription(
                RedisDataTypeDescription.RedisDataType.HASH, hashKey);
        }

        @Override
        public RedisDataTypeDescription getDataTypeDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        @Override
        public String getKeyFromTuple(ITuple tuple) {
            return tuple.getStringByField("word");
        }

        @Override
        public String getValueFromTuple(ITuple tuple) {
            return tuple.getStringByField("count");
        }
    }
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Storm.practice</groupId>
  <artifactId>Storm.Prova</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Storm.Prova</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> #error from here...
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-redis</artifactId>
    <version>{0.9.1-incubating}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>#... to here
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>Storm.practice.Storm.Prova.ProvaTopology</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

The errors are that Eclipse can't find the dependences and the packages

Comment: Hi Amnor, have you tried something? That would help someone who knows this stuf (certainly not me!) to point where you need to be going.

Comment: I tried Flask and  Redis  , and didn't work for me. Tried using this tutorial. https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud381/l-2731858540/m-3170538543

Comment: Any help? internet it's almost empty if we are talking about this... at least I haven't found information about howto do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now it's a bit late, almost a year, but I was reviewing my account, and saw this question.

I finally used Redis, interfaced wit Jedis, that I import as a Maven artifact. Once this was working and I was able to see the results with the Redis Monitor via telnet, I created a simple Node.js code, launched it, and the data was arriving to the client, hence to d3. I needed Socket.io and Redis.js to achieve this, but is working now.

If someone need some details, please, ask me and I will help you happily.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on this? Would be very helpful :)

Comment: Of course, which part would you like to learn about? since then, I've learned a lot, and I could explain what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your scenario, I think you will need some system or code in the middle that will read data from Storm and push to D3. You can try out something like WSO2 CEP [1], which has the ability to connect to Storm and uses websockets to push events to a dashboard based on d3 [2].

In your scenario, you can map your logic in the Storm bolt to a Siddhi query [3] and then get those events from Storm to WSO2 CEP. Then you can create a websocket publisher to send events to your D3 code using the built-in websocket capabilities of the server.

Please note that this is one of the possible solutions based on your requirements and you might be better off utilizing the capabilities of an already existing CEP system that has integration to Storm and D3.

Hope this helps!

[1] http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Visualizing+Results+in+the+Analytics+Dashboard

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Sample+0501+-+Processing+a+Simple+Filter+Query+with+Apache+Storm+Deployment

Comment: Thanks a lot!, i will try it inmediately, as soon as I have it done, i'll post my results.

Comment: At first, thanks for your help. But my project chief wants to use redis and flask... so i'm trying now to do the connection with that. It's my degree ending project, and he wants it to be displayed using my original d3 code. Now i'm coding the python flask, i'm sure it won't work at first try, I'm noob with these tech, so I may edit my question soon.